# Delete last node in singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

In a [TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux) Linus Torvalds made a point about *“good taste”* at approximately [14:10 in the interview](https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux#t-850000). I read through his examples of *“bad taste”* and *“good taste”* and wanted to implement the same principle for a function that deletes the last node in a singly linked list. I also followed [his coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* linked list structure */
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

/* create new node */
struct node *new_node(int data, struct node *next)
{
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    if (!new) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}

/* delete last node */
void delete_last(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: linked list underflow\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct node **cursor = &head;
    while ((*cursor)->next != NULL)
        cursor = &(*cursor)->next;
    free(*cursor);
    *cursor = NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's generally not good taste to `exit()` from a minor function call.

Comment: @MrR Alright, what's the alternative?

Comment: Instead of `void` make it `int` (or if you like bools, add the `stdbool` header) and return something to indicate the failure to the calling function.

Comment: As @debdutdeb said - have an error code, or in the case of delete (if there is no list the after effect is the same - there is still no list / there is 1 least node on the end - so it's not so much an error).   AND of course the `new_node` method either needs documentation or is a `new_element_before` because it's not inserting at a random point it's inserting in a way that would break an existing list (if you put it say before the last element) - you'd end up with a final node pointed to by two nodes.

Comment: Lots of good advice over here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136077/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list - it's C++ but is more C like than not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite presumptive for a function to exit the program like this:

> ```
>     if (!new) {
>             fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed\n");
>             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>     }
> ```

I'd argue that the caller is also better positioned to know whether an error message is useful, too:

```
    if (!new) {
            return new;
    }
```

Similarly, removing from empty list is better conveyed by a return value.

Explicit comparison against `NULL` seems clunky to me (and inconsistent with the test of `new` above), given that pointers have a well-understood truthiness:

```
if (!head) {
```

```
while ((*cursor)->next)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I also followed [Torvalds'] coding style

I'm all for coding style standards, though I decline to listen to all of his suggestions simply because he's the loudest (seriously, very very loud) voice in the room. His blind obedience to 1988's K&R with no other rationale I find short-sighted as well. Anyway, enough editorializing:

Your non-parenthesized `sizeof *new` falls on a matter in his guide that is a little ambiguous -

> The notable exceptions are `sizeof`, `typeof`, `alignof`, and `__attribute__`, which look somewhat like functions (and are usually used with parentheses in Linux, although they are not required in the language)

Whereas parens are not required after `sizeof`, I see them in the majority of code I encounter so I'd recommend sticking with them.

I warn against writing keywords from C++ as symbol names in C, in this case `new`. If ever you want this to be readily C++-compatible, this will cause you grief.

Comment: I differ here, and don't like unnecessary parens when using `sizeof` - I find that helps draw attention to `sizeof (type)` as opposed to `sizeof expr`.  As you say, it's all personal preference, and being consistent is what matters most.